# Tracks in cloud chambers (Mott’s problem) and quantum state reduction (collapse)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

After reading Mott’s paper

https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1929.0205

**The wave mechanics of α-ray tracks**

Mott N.F., Proc. R. Soc. Lond. A, 126, 79-84, 1929.

my simple question is why this kind of reasoning isn’t sufficient to show that any kind of quantum state reduction (projection postulate, collapse of the wave function) is  *unnecessary*.

Of course this does not rule out the idea to use the quantum state reduction as a tool in some calculations, but as presented in some books and lecture notes it seems that the quantum state reduction ist still believed to be an essential, indispensable postulate for quantum mechanics.

(of course I know that there *are* non-collapse interpretations; to my knowledge they haven’t been ruled out experimentally but agree with observations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point of Mott's paper is that appear tracks  and not other patterns because there is enough energy just for that. Taking wavefunctions as configurations, you should  study the wave-mechanical configurations in an hypersphere and then translating it in the 3d space.

Collapse is a non-sense   cartoon, just related to measurement, that at the end is where the paradigma of quantas really comes from. If true, all matter should radiate as hell ! (since neither the two momentums and the enegy should be conserved in a collapse)  I think it is the time to admit that we did not get the process. That is clearly a non-linear dynamics where an instability drives the whole system particle+apparatus in a final state with a classical outcomes. I think that quantas are just an illusion of this process. And  this is also the source of the big disconnection we have in physics between the micro and the macro.
Here one can expect the next big thing.

Comment: I agree with the "non-sense cartoon" but I have problems with this just being told and taught over and over again. Your ideas about "non-linear dynamics" and "instability" remind me to what I read in Neumaiers Thermal Interpretation papers -- with great ideas but no solid calculation. Do you know of any concrete references? Do you see a way to go beyond decoherence (which seems to solve only a small subset of the problems - certainly not the collapse problem)?

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the non-linearity has to be such that to affect only macroscopic objects, that is negligible at microscopic level, to not change predictions like Hydrogen atom spectra. The hard problem is that to consider wavefunction configurations is mathematically hard as hell. There are no real idea on the table. Some collapse models like GWR and Penrose.

Comment: Thinking about them they don't look like physics and they have a lot of problems like violating any possible conservation laws. Plus (for me) they don't solve the measurement problem since they decouple the apparatus (macroscopic and  already collapsed) from "particle" to measure (microscopic , still quantum). So if the apparatus is already collapsed , it seems you have to go back to call decoherence theory.  Agree, decoherence is just a way to say we don't know, you can 't block macrospic superpositions in linear QM and it postulate a classic environment (which is the thing to explain .. ).

Comment: Of course, What I had written in the initial comment above is assuming that Schrodinger equation and quantum mechanics are related to something. But there could be something totally different that none have ever been able to imagine.

Comment: We partially found a trick to reduce wavefunction configurations to guassian random variables. I did not want to post my own stuff. But I have a preprint version to be modified for the end of January. We proved that considering Quantum spin chains without "measured ensembles", if you want to get phase transitions, you have to add an energy that block macroscopic superpositions, i.e. macroscopic cat. The result is in three theorems, one is a numerical proof (computer used to search some minima which are not possible to get by pure hands). The modification has a clear test to be rejected.

Comment: I don't think it is about interpretations but to find a different physics. None can verify things like Born's rule or Heisenberg principle (deduced from a single wave-packet, i.e. something not existing for particle+apparatus). It will be essential improving the ability to manipulate matter at the quantum-classical boundary. We are already observing large objects in superpositions (small cat state) and also continuous spectra. So QM will need modifications. But it will take time. Manipulating matter is very hard as much as doing computations taking all possible configurations of QM.

Comment: I am not sure if QM requires modifications - except eliminating the collaps postulate. AFAIK nobody has a no-go theorem that QM applied to systems like „quantum object + apparatus + environment“ does NOT create individual localized particle-like detection events - satisfying Born‘s rule. But that’s all we miss. So instead of i) postulating the result or ii) modifying the theory there’s still the option iii) to find these results strictly applying the Schrödinger equation to quantum many body systems. I would go for (ii) IFF I see a no-go theorem for (iii).

Comment: No go theorems have never had a role in science and they  will never have it. Because everyone does some desired assumption to get the desidered conclusion. The good thing  is assuming principles to deduce things.I don't agree that there is no no-go-theorem, Schr. cat paper explained well, linear QM will always create macroscopic dispersion, i.e. delocalized macroscopic object (the pointers) and this is why Von Neumann said that QM can not be formulated observer independent. The environment/decoherence assumption is the same thing of taking multiverse of Everett, not usefull for anything.

Comment: There is no reason why the environment is classical .. it is made of atoms and these are still quantum. There is neither chaos in QM (which has infinite conserved quantities (this is not physics)), how do you explain exponential divergences of trajectories .

Comment: I don't understand this fixation about Born's rule, how  do you verify it in Stern-Gerlach for example: 1) you have lip print no two dots, I don't see any relation with the particle had spin 1/2 or -1/2 statistics of two dots; 2) how can you can reconstruct the statistics from the unknow wave-particle-packet?   What you really see is one phographic grains reacting at a time because of energy conservation and little by little you reconstruct the real interference figure.

Comment: From my personal perspectives, having worked in hydrodynamics derived from silly stochastic models,  we have no decent physics to derive the law of macroscopic world. QM is an atomic theory, nothing more. What we have to respect about data is the linearity of Schr. equ. at atomic level to get those spectra and modify the theory for many atoms, saying what one  expects to observe of different in an ideal experiment for a scalable quantum object.  Environment just creates another arbitrary division between macro and micro (exactly as the observer).

Comment: Here a no-go-theorem assuming QM. You can write and solve it with mathematics: take a large magnetic object not subject to external magnetic fields, the magnetism is given by the spins, the configuration are psi(S_1, .....S_N) (consider only z-axis). The Environment, since not magnetic will not do anything, but since you have a Hamitonian motion (Schr. eq is a formal Hamiltonian system with Q_i, P_i) given by H(psi),  the system will evolves by energy conservation in a macroscopic magnetic cat , because the cat of two magnetized states has the same energy of them .

Answer (score 4):

This is a very good question, and I think the answer is yes.  But Mott’s paper on its own doesn’t provide the answer because (at best) it says alpha particles form tracks but it doesn’t say why any one particular track is selected.  I have recently published a paper in Foundations of Physics that offers a new physical analysis of how the selection takes place.  The title is “The first droplet in a cloud chamber track,” and it’s [available online](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10701-021-00452-x).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, I think it depends on a point of view. Mott showed that straight tracks are consistent with the Schrodinger equation. So if the point of view is that the world is a solution to the Schrodinger equation, then yes, Mott's analysis is enough.

Here's my simple version of the ideas in Mott's paper, which I think is a little more accessible than the original.

Mott problem

Consider the emission of an $\alpha$ particle in a cloud chamber.
The quantum mechanical model of an $\alpha$ particle is a spherical
wave emanating from the origin.
A spherical wave should ionize atoms throughout the cloud chamber.
However, only straight tracks are observed.
Nevill Mott showed that straight tracks are consistent with the Schrodinger equation.

Let $\mathbf R$ be the position of the $\alpha$ particle,
let $\mathbf a_1$ and $\mathbf a_2$ be the positions of two atoms ionized by the $\alpha$ particle,
and let $\mathbf r_1$ and $\mathbf r_2$ be the positions of the free electrons.
The Hamiltonian for the system is
\begin{equation*}
\hat H=\hat K_\alpha+\hat K_1+\hat K_2+U_1+U_2+V_1+V_2
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{align*}
\hat K_\alpha&=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2M}\nabla_\alpha^2 & & \text{kinetic energy of $\alpha$ particle}
\\[1ex]
\hat K_1&=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla_1^2 & & \text{kinetic energy of 1st electron}
\\[1ex]
\hat K_2&=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla_2^2 & & \text{kinetic energy of 2nd electron}
\\[1ex]
U_1&=-\frac{e^2}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf a_1|} & & \text{potential energy of 1st electron}
\\[1ex]
U_2&=-\frac{e^2}{|\mathbf r_2-\mathbf a_2|} & & \text{potential energy of 2nd electron}
\\[1ex]
V_1&=-\frac{2e^2}{|\mathbf R-\mathbf r_1|} & & \text{potential energy of $\alpha$ and 1st electron}
\\[1ex]
V_2&=-\frac{2e^2}{|\mathbf R-\mathbf r_2|} & & \text{potential energy of $\alpha$ and 2nd electron}
\end{align*}

Let $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ be atomic wavefunctions such that
\begin{equation*}
\left(\hat K_1+U_1\right)\psi_1=E_1\psi_1,
\quad
\left(\hat K_2+U_2\right)\psi_2=E_2\psi_2
\end{equation*}

We want to find a wavefunction $F(\mathbf R,\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\hat HF=EF
\end{equation*}

Let
\begin{equation*}
F=F_0+F_1+F_2+\cdots
\end{equation*}
and let
\begin{equation*}
\hat H_0=\hat K_\alpha+E_1+E_2
\end{equation*}

Start by finding an $F_0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\hat H_0F_0=EF_0
\end{equation*}

The solution is
\begin{equation*}
F_0(\mathbf R,\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2)=f_0(\mathbf R)\psi_1(\mathbf r_1-\mathbf a_1)\psi_2(\mathbf r_2-\mathbf a_2)
\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
f_0(\mathbf R)=\frac{1}{|\mathbf R|}\exp\left(\frac{ik|\mathbf R|}{\hbar}\right),\quad k=\sqrt{2M(E-E_1-E_2)}
\end{equation*}

It follows that for the full Hamiltonian $\hat H$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\hat HF_0=EF_0+(V_1+V_2)F_0
\end{equation*}

To cancel $(V_1+V_2)F_0$ from the full Hamiltonian, find an $F_1$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\hat H_0F_1=EF_1-(V_1+V_2)F_0
\end{equation*}

Rewrite as
\begin{equation*}
\left(\hat H_0-E\right)F_1=-(V_1+V_2)F_0
\end{equation*}

Expand $F_1$ and $F_0$.
\begin{multline*}
\left(\hat H_0-E\right)f_1(\mathbf R)\psi_1(\mathbf r_1-\mathbf a_1)\psi_2(\mathbf r_2-\mathbf a_2)
\\
=-(V_1+V_2)f_0(\mathbf R)\psi_1(\mathbf r_1-\mathbf a_1)\psi_2(\mathbf r_2-\mathbf a_2)
\end{multline*}

To solve for $f_1(\mathbf R)$ multiply both sides by
\begin{equation*}
\psi_1^*(\mathbf r_1-\mathbf a_1)\psi_2^*(\mathbf r_2-\mathbf a_2)
\end{equation*}
and integrate over $\mathbf r_1$ and $\mathbf r_2$ to obtain
\begin{equation*}
\left(\hat H_0-E\right)f_1(\mathbf R)
=V_1(\mathbf R)f_0(\mathbf R)+V_2(\mathbf R)f_0(\mathbf R)
\tag{2}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
V_1(\mathbf R)=
2e^2\int\frac{|\psi_1(\mathbf r)|^2}{|\mathbf R-\mathbf a_1-\mathbf r|}\,d\mathbf r,
\quad
V_2(\mathbf R)=
2e^2\int\frac{|\psi_2(\mathbf r)|^2}{|\mathbf R-\mathbf a_2-\mathbf r|}\,d\mathbf r
\end{equation*}

Per Mott the solution to (2) is
\begin{multline*}
f_1(\mathbf R)=
\frac{M}{2\pi\hbar^2}\int\frac{V_1(\mathbf r)f_0(\mathbf r)}{|\mathbf R-\mathbf r|}
\exp\left(\frac{ik|\mathbf R-\mathbf r|}{\hbar}\right)\,d\mathbf r
\\
{}+\frac{M}{2\pi\hbar^2}\int\frac{V_2(\mathbf r)f_0(\mathbf r)}{|\mathbf R-\mathbf r|}
\exp\left(\frac{ik|\mathbf R-\mathbf r|}{\hbar}\right)\,d\mathbf r
\end{multline*}

Let $I_1$ be the first integral.
Substitute for $f_0$ in $I_1$ to obtain
\begin{equation*}
I_1(\mathbf R)=
\frac{M}{2\pi\hbar^2}\int\frac{V_1(\mathbf r)}{|\mathbf R-\mathbf r||\mathbf r|}
\exp\left(\frac{ik|\mathbf R-\mathbf r|}{\hbar}+\frac{ik|\mathbf r|}{\hbar}\right)\,d\mathbf r
\end{equation*}

Change of variable $\mathbf r\rightarrow\mathbf r+\mathbf a_1$
\begin{equation*}
I_1(\mathbf R)=
\frac{M}{2\pi\hbar^2}
\int
\frac{V_1(\mathbf r+\mathbf a_1)}{|\mathbf R-\mathbf r-\mathbf a_1||\mathbf r+\mathbf a_1|}
\exp\left(
\frac{ik|\mathbf R-\mathbf r-\mathbf a_1|}{\hbar}+\frac{ik|\mathbf r+\mathbf a_1|}{\hbar}
\right)\,d\mathbf r
\end{equation*}

Per Mott (see also Figari and Teta)
\begin{multline*}
I_1(\mathbf R)\approx\frac{1}{|\mathbf R-\mathbf a_1|}
\exp\left(\frac{ik|\mathbf R-\mathbf a_1|}{\hbar}\right)
\\
{}\times
\frac{M}{2\pi\hbar^2}
\int
\frac{V_1(\mathbf r+\mathbf a_1)}{|\mathbf r+\mathbf a_1|}
\exp\left(-\frac{ik\mathbf u_1(\mathbf R)\cdot\mathbf r}{\hbar}
+\frac{ik|\mathbf r+\mathbf a_1|}{\hbar}\right)
\,d\mathbf r
\end{multline*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf u_1(\mathbf R)=\frac{\mathbf R-\mathbf a_1}{|\mathbf R-\mathbf a_1|}
\end{equation*}

The condition for stationary phase is
\begin{equation*}
g'=\frac{d}{d\mathbf r}\left(-\mathbf u_1(\mathbf R)\cdot\mathbf r+|\mathbf r+\mathbf a_1|\right)
=-\mathbf u_1(\mathbf R)+\frac{\mathbf r+\mathbf a_1}{|\mathbf r+\mathbf a_1|}=0
\end{equation*}

Note that $V_1(\mathbf r+\mathbf a_1)$ is small except for $\mathbf r\approx0$ so
we only require stationarity at the origin.
Hence for $\mathbf r=0$ the integral is stationary ($g'=0$)
when $\mathbf R$ satisfies the condition
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf u_1(\mathbf R)
=\frac{\mathbf a_1}{|\mathbf a_1|}
\end{equation*}

By symmetry of the integrals, $I_2$ is stationary when $\mathbf R$ satisfies the condition
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf u_2(\mathbf R)
=\frac{\mathbf a_2}{|\mathbf a_2|}
\end{equation*}

Because nonstationary integrals vanish we have
\begin{equation*}
f_1(\mathbf R)=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& I_1(\mathbf R),
& \mathbf u_1(\mathbf R)=\frac{\mathbf a_1}{|\mathbf a_1|}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mathbf u_2(\mathbf R)\ne\frac{\mathbf a_2}{|\mathbf a_2|}
\\
& I_2(\mathbf R),
& \mathbf u_1(\mathbf R)\ne\frac{\mathbf a_1}{|\mathbf a_1|}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mathbf u_2(\mathbf R)=\frac{\mathbf a_2}{|\mathbf a_2|}
\\
& I_1(\mathbf R)+I_2(\mathbf R),
& \mathbf u_1(\mathbf R)=\frac{\mathbf a_1}{|\mathbf a_1|}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mathbf u_2(\mathbf R)=\frac{\mathbf a_2}{|\mathbf a_2|}
\\
& 0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*}

The first two cases represent states in which just one atom is ionized.
The third case has both $V_1$ and $V_2$ contributing to $f_1$.
Hence when both atoms are ionized we have
\begin{equation*}
f_1(\mathbf R)=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& I_1(\mathbf R)+I_2(\mathbf R),
& \frac{\mathbf a_1}{|\mathbf a_1|}=\frac{\mathbf a_2}{|\mathbf a_2|}
\\
& 0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*}

To satisfy the condition, $\mathbf a_1$ and $\mathbf a_2$
must be on the same ray emanating from the origin.
Hence straight tracks are consistent with the Schrodinger equation.

Note

The condition for stationarity
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf u_1(\mathbf R)
=\frac{\mathbf R-\mathbf a_1}{|\mathbf R-\mathbf a_1|}
=\frac{\mathbf a_1}{|\mathbf a_1|}
\end{equation*}
is satisfied by all $\mathbf R$ and constant $c>1$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf R=c\mathbf a_1
\end{equation*}

Condition $c>1$ implies that $|\mathbf R|>|\mathbf a_1|$
so technically the condition
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathbf a_1}{|\mathbf a_1|}=\frac{\mathbf a_2}{|\mathbf a_2|}
\end{equation*}
is less stringent than
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf u_1(\mathbf R)=\frac{\mathbf a_1}{|\mathbf a_1|}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mathbf u_2(\mathbf R)=\frac{\mathbf a_2}{|\mathbf a_2|}
\end{equation*}

The exact condition for stationarity of both $I_1$ and $I_2$ is
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathbf a_1}{|\mathbf a_1|}=\frac{\mathbf a_2}{|\mathbf a_2|}
\quad\text{and}\quad
|\mathbf R|>\max(|\mathbf a_1|,|\mathbf a_2|)
\end{equation*}